# NextJs can't get data from Laravel API

Tags: laravel, nginx, next.js

I am working with Laravel, NextJs and Docker. I can get data from the browser and Postman but when I try to get data with NextJs I got an error.

In nextJs I have Pages/surfaces.js

```
import AdminLayout from "../../modules/admin/layout/AdminLayout";
import Table from "../../sharedComponents/Table";
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { ContentHeader } from "../../modules/admin/SharedComponents/ContentHeader/ContentHeader";
import { ConfigDataTable } from "../../modules/admin/Surfaces/ConfigDataTable";

export default function Surfaces() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  
  return (
    <>
      <ContentHeader title={t('surfaces')} isCRUD={false} />
      <Table config={ConfigDataTable()} data={[]} />
    </>
  );
}

Surfaces.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <AdminLayout>{page}</AdminLayout>;
};

export async function getServerSideProps({locale}) {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5001/api/surfaces/');

  console.log('ggg ',  await response.json());


  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale))
    }
  }
}
```

Nginx

```
server {
    listen  80;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/public;

    server_name  finaldraw.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass nadal:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Laravel has CORS:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, lang')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
    }
```

URI:

> http://localhost:5001/api/surfaces

Postman result:

[image]

Browser Result

[image]

NextJs Error

[image]

Console:

[image]

[image]

Response tab is the code we see in the browser:

[image]

and in the terminal we see:

[image]

Comment: anything in the console or network tab?

Comment: nothing in the console

Comment: You added the console output, I can there is `500 Internal Server error` which should be pretty clear reason of the issue. Have you check what in the response tab?

Comment: Can you the preview tab? As it's an one line html, better to show what that html represent.

Comment: it's  a blank page @Imran. I don't understand why work in the browser or postman but here not

Comment: Then can you copy the reponse html and paste it some online html previewer(eg. https://htmlcodeeditor.com) to see that's written there? Besides, as it's 500 error, you might even have something in laravel log. You can see laravel long in `storage/logs`

Comment: I don't know what is the exact reason why it's not working from nextjs. But as we have a clue already, we might be able to know the reason.

Comment: Which is a clue? We don't have an specific error

Comment: The clue is the 500 Internal Server Error and what you have in the response tab. Just preview the response tab somehere. See my previous comment for link for a html preview. Paste the content of response tab on that website and see what it shows by rendering the html.

Comment: the laravel log is empty and I updated the post with the htmlcodeeditor

Comment: Another clue @Imran. If I use the fetch inside useEffect this works, but in server side not

Comment: The problem is between container communications, when Next try to access the data in other container fails @Imran

Comment: Ops, nice to see that you find it out. I had no clue.

Comment: I have same problem too...client side everything ok...server side not